# How to optimize the regex match, getting two different path

Tags: regex

I have image urls like the following two.

> http://www.google.piano-1398069_1280.jpg?AccessKey=LTAIQ8
>
> http://www.google.piano_8069_1280.png?AccessKey=LTAI

I need to extract the path of url , as the cache key for the downloaded images.

Here is my regex `.+jpg|.+png`

Any way to optimize it , such as to reduce a `.+`

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? Performance? Would `.+(jpg|png)` or `.+\.(?:jpg|png)` help? Note that it's pretty brittle because it'll fail if some additional part happens to have `jpg` or `png` as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

`(?i)^https?:\/\/(?:w{3}\.)\S+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif|other_extensions)` is more than expected.
(offered by  Emma )

`.+(jpg|png)` , `.+\.(?:jpg|png)` is what I ask. (offered by  ggorlen)